# Android 4.4 socketio can't connect to https link

Tags: socket.io, android-4.4-kitkat

I know this is an old question but I really tried every method online and none of them works for me. I really don't know what to do.

I'm trying to connect my Android 4.4 to node.js by socketIO. I'm using gottox's client: https://github.com/Gottox  my socket address is a https link. so I read through lots of articles about the incompatible of this api and https connection.

so I changed the websocketTransport class as suggested as follow:

```
 public WebsocketTransport(URI uri, IOConnection connection) {
        super(uri);
        this.connection = connection;
        SSLContext context = null;
        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "HarmonyJSSE");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        try {
            context.init(null, null, null);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if("wss".equals(uri.getScheme()) && context != null) {
            this.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(context));
        }
    }
```

and my code to connect to the socketIO is:

```
// connecting node server
            Log.v("connect to node server", "");
            SocketIO socket = new SocketIO();
            SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
            socket.addHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + sessID);
            socket.connect("https://live.xxxxxxxx.com:8080/",new IOCallback() {

                @Override
                public void on(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1,
                        Object... arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnect() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnect() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    arg0.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

for my node server, I need to pass a phpsessid in the header, so I added the header as above. but everytime I still got silence mistake. it just didn't work.

here's my log:

```
io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:335)
at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:294)
at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:201)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:689)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:316)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:320)
... 2 more
I/io.socket(9077): Cleanup
```

I have no idea what's going on but I think the problem is android is still using it's own crap ssl factory. so anyone know how to solve this? I read online that android 4.4 r using different standard for https. Is that the problem?

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate ?